# How to keep an element relative to an other one at the same level?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two elements, and I want the second one to stick to the first one, so when the screen size is changing, the second element keep the same position from the first one.

```js
var bubbleBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('qkb-bubble-btn ')[0];
var badge = document.getElementsByClassName('badge ')[0];
var rect = bubbleBtn.getBoundingClientRect();

badge.style.left = (rect.left+30)+'px';
badge.style.top = (rect.top-20) +'px';
```

```css
.badge {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.qkb-bubble-btn {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #FF7756 !important;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <button class="qkb-bubble-btn">test</button>
    <span class="badge">3</span>
  </div>
```

I don't know how to show my problem in the snippet but basically the whole app is reponsive so the bubble button is moving when the screen is resized and I want the badge to always be at this position from the button.

Is it possible only using CSS ? or should I trigger my JS code everytime the screen is resized ?

Comment: Have you considered using a CSS pseudo element? If the bubble is just a label the entire thing could be achieved with CSS (no JS and no second HTML element)

Comment: @DBS that could be a great idea indeed, but I want to be able to set the value from JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your position I'd prefer to go css only setting the button position to relative and adding a css rule defining an :after element being your icon positioned absolute.

The side effect is that the content will need to be set the css way.

In this new edited demo I added the chance to specificy `content` addressing the attribute `data-number` and added a class to the rule so that it will show the bubble only if such class is present.

```js
//for the sake of showing how to dynamically change the attribute driving the "boing"
function increment(){
  const target = document.querySelector('.showbubble');
  target.dataset.number = parseInt(target.dataset.number)+1;
}
```

```css
.qkb-bubble-btn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FF7756 !important;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.qkb-bubble-btn.showbubble:after {  
  position: absolute;
  right:-25px;
  top:-20px;
  content: attr(data-number);
  
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.trigger{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 25px;">
    <button class="qkb-bubble-btn showbubble" data-number="3">test (showing)</button>
    <br>
    <button class="qkb-bubble-btn">test (hiding)</button>
    
    <br>
    <button class="trigger" onclick="increment();">Increment counter +1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty good idea, but the badge shouldn't always be displayed, and I guess with your solution I can't control when to display it or not

Comment: I think the number "3" is dynamic, you need to pass this through `att()`

Answer (score 0):

The parent `div` should have `position: relative` and `display: inline-block` to relate the position and to give width equal to button.

```css
.badge-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: inline-block
}
.badge {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  right: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}

.qkb-bubble-btn {
  
  background-color: #FF7756 !important;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="badge-wrapper">
    <button class="qkb-bubble-btn">test</button>
    <span class="badge">3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add it but I can't because the button is part of a component which I can't modify the source code

Comment: @J.erome I have modify the answer

Comment: I'm testing it :)

Comment: I hope you have removed the `badge.style.left = (rect.left+30)+'px'; badge.style.top = (rect.top-20) +'px';` and have added the css

Comment: I did but for a reason the badge isn't at the right place, I'm looking what is wrong in my code and it doens't move with the button when I resize the page

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code as follows this should help you.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.badge {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:20px;
 
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.qkb-bubble-btn {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #FF7756 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button class="qkb-bubble-btn">test</button>
    <span class="badge">3</span>
  </div>
```

You don't need the Javascript code for this.